# Is it possible to keep .gitignore files out of SVN?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm using `git svn` to merge changes from my local git repository to an SVN server.  However, when I issue `git svn dcommit` it will actually commit any .gitignore files that I have in my source tree.  This is even after I've checked out the SVN repository locally (using SVN), set the svn:ignore property (recursively, listing .gitignore as one of the files to ignore), and then committing that property change directly to SVN.

Is this intended behaviour?  A bug?  Is there a work around that anyone knows of to keep .gitignore out of SVN?

I just know a non-git user on my team is going to see these files and start deleting them, then the next time I go to `rebase/dcommit` a lot of unwanted files are going to wind up in SVN.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Git's repo-specific "exclude" file, instead of using `.gitignore` files. The "exclude" file resides at `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` (where `$GIT_DIR` is the Git repository directory, usually `.git`). The format of this file is exactly the same as that of .gitignore files. The difference is that this is a repository-specific file -- it will only exist in your repository. It will not be propagated to any other repositories (e.g. via `git clone` or `git svn dcommit`).

There is no way to omit `.gitignore` files from the SVN repo, but keep them in Git. Any attempt to do so would result in your local commits not matching the commits that git-svn retrieves from the SVN server. In other words, your local repository's history would not be reconcilable with the history from SVN; they would be permanently out-of-sync.

Comment: Good to know about the repo-ignores and also that I'm not the only one who can't keep those pesky .gitignore files out of SVN!

Comment: It seems that the file is now called `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` without plural-s.

Comment: @JannikJochem I think that was just a typo on my part. As far as I know, it has always been named "exclude", not "excludes". Thank you for pointing that out! :)